# Selectively including <select> fields in output array

Tags: php, html

I have a page with a bunch of in individual  fields, the results of which are all conglomerated into an array by using a value="array[]" attribute. However, on form submit some of the select fields may be hidden, currently those that are hidden still post values to the array, how can I make it so only select fields that are visible will post to the array?

Thanks

Comment: Are these items hidden through client-side code or server-side code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set an input's `disabled` attribute to `disabled` to prevent it from being part of the form submit:

`<input type="text" style="display:none" disabled="disabled" />`

Comment: yea that would work perfectly, and I can just use Jquery to add and remove the attribute depending on visibility. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order for the fields to *not* submit their data through, you have to prevent that data from coming through on the client side, either by manipulating the HTML or using Javascript to intercept the form-post.